How to calculate LULC areas in 1km grid cell
I want to carry out a LULC analysis using Catchment scale LULC data of Australia (50m resolution), using 1km x 1km cells (fishnet tool). I have a 50 m LULC shp file (NSW) and created a km x 1km grid fishnet. Please help me to calculate area of each LULC type within each 1km x 1km grid.
Tried zonal statistics  tool in Arc Pro. However wont calculate area of each LULC class
